# UV4L webRTC demo crashes Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: uv4l, webrtc

When I access the UV4L webRTC video streaming demo (https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/tutorials/custom-webapp-with-face-detection/) from my android device my Raspberry Pi 3 crashes.
Connecting to the demo from any other device work fine.

I have no idea why this is happening, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uv4l is not yet supported on raspbian strectch (debian 9)